# Deny calling 'localhost', 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 from the service endpoint running in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a service that exposes endpoint, the main purpose of which is to perform custom HTTP call based on JSON data provided (URL, port, body, headers etc.).
The service is running inside Docker container on Cloud environment.

How do I prevent user from being able to make circular calls to the server itself for ex. `post  http://myservice.com/invoke body: {'url': 'localhost:8080/invoke', 'method': 'get'}`

and how to deny 'localhost', '0.0.0.0' or '127.0.0.1' urls so the server was unable to find and call them inside container and execute requests for not exposed endpoints? (for ex. my service also has `'\stats'` endpoint that's not accessible from public VPC but accessible inside private VPC, so calling `'myservice.com/invoke {'url': 'localhost:8080/stats', 'method': 'get'}'` will make this endpoint accessible to user outside private VPC).

My simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
COPY build/my-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner my-service
RUN chmod +x my-service
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./my-service"]
```

Thank you

Comment: I assume that server and client are in different computers so you don't want the user be able to make a request from his computer to localhost in server computer, right?
Then I missundestood the second point, can you explain a little bit more please.

Comment: updated description of the issue

Comment: Ok, if I understand in the right way you call a service inside the server 
through the `http://myservice.com/invoke` endpoint and you want to be able to call the "public" services from this endpoint but no the "private" ones. Maybe you can achieve this with an extra service that handles the requests from outsite of the VPC. An nginx reverse proxy could be suitable for this

Comment: we limited outbound traffic for the 'myservice' with cloud  provider security rules. The only issue remaining is 'localhost' and 127.0.0.1 that can be provided as 'url' in request body. Cloud provider can't limit this case

Comment: It makes sense since you cannot limit the access of your own localhost, it's a bit weird, thats the point of using a reverse proxy. Another solution could be use of CORS and set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `127.0.0.1` to those "private" endpoints and keep the access from within the cloud but no from the outside since the origin of the request will be different than `localhost`.